# JQuery Remove all links inside a <div> that have a particular class except for the one that's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, how can I `remove/disable` or `change the class` of all links inside a `<div>` that have a particular `class` except for the one that was clicked? The clicked one's class needs to be changed.

```
<div class="test">
<div class="link" data-id="1">Link 1</div>
<div class="link" data-id="2">Link 2</div>
<div class="link" data-id="3">Link 3</div>
</div>
```

In this case, if I clicked `Link 1`, I'm trying to make `Link 2` and `Link 3` disappear or change their class, and change the class of Link 1 to `noLink`.

How can this be done. I'm familiar with add class, remove class, but I'm stuck with getting all others to be removed or changed and change the clicked one to another class.

Comment: I was about to, but others replied before that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$('.test div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('link')
           .addClass('noLink')
           .siblings('.link')
           .remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mshHt/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change color of clicked link then you can use following code

```
 $('.test .link').on('click',function(){
    $('.test .link').css('background', '#38a2de');
    $(this).css('background', '#333333');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pCFNK/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    $('.link').addClass('hide');
    $(this).attr('class', 'no-link');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3586/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link').click(function(){

       $(this).addClass('noLink').removeClass('link').siblings().hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.test .link').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('link').addClass('noLink');
    $('.link').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
<script>
    $('.test .link').click(function(){
        $('.test .link').hide();
        $(this).addClass('noLink').show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('link').addClass('nolink');
  $('.link').remove()
});
```